# How to handle MySQL deadlock error in CodeIgniter 3.x

Tags: codeigniter-3, deadlock

How to handle MySQL deadlock error in CodeIgniter 3.x
Tried normal try catch option , but its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps to handle mySQL deadlock in Codeigniter-3.

1. Enable the $config['db_debug'] = TRUE
2. Catch the deadlock error using try-catch. Use this CI_DB_mysqli_utility::DB_ERROR_DEADLOCK constant in Codeigniter to catch the error.

Sample code:

```
try{
    //mysql query execution
 }
 catch(Exception $e){
    if ($e->getCode() == CI_DB_mysqli_utility::DB_ERROR_DEADLOCK) {
        // Handle deadlock error
        // For example, retry the operation after a delay
        sleep(2); // Sleep for 2 seconds before retrying
        // Retry the database operation
    } else {
        // Handle other database errors
        log_message('error', 'Database error: ' . $e->getMessage());
        // Throw or handle the error as needed
    }
}
```

These steps worked out for me.
------------------------ New Edit -----------------------------------
If you can't edit the config value in production. You can set the config dynamically within your method by using the below function.

```
function set_db_debug($enable_db_debug) {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->config->load('config');
    $CI->config->set_item('db_debug', $enable_db_debug);
}
```

Comment: Prabha Chetty : I cant change the config value 
 $config['db_debug'] = TRUE

Comment: @Ras4U You have to edit this value in config.php file of codeigniter in the production environment. If you can't edit this file, you can dynamically set the db_debug config. Please find my last edit in the answer.